# xslt - get last row from a foreach loop (split into 3 columns)

Tags: xslt, loops, foreach

I'm looping through 1-20 `<li>`'s using xslt and I'm trying to figure out how to add a class to the last row of the list, when displayed in a 3 column grid type format.

At the moment, I'm using this code to add a class of `col-last` to every 3rd column in the list.

```
<xsl:if test="not(position() mod 3)">
  <xsl:attribute name="class">col-last</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Is there a way I can add a class of "row-last" to the last row, considering they may be 1-3 items on it?

***Example***

**4 items**

```
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li class="col-last">Item 3</li>
<li class="row-last">Item 4</li>
```

**5 Items**

```
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li class="col-last">Item 3</li>
<li class="row-last">Item 4</li>
<li class="row-last">Item 5</li>
```

**6 Items**

```
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li class="col-last">Item 3</li>
<li class="row-last">Item 4</li>
<li class="row-last">Item 5</li>
<li class="row-last col-last">Item 6</li>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="class">
                <xsl:if test="position() > last() - last() mod 3 - 3 * not(last() mod 3)">row-last </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="not(position() mod 3)">col-last </xsl:if>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$class != ''">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($class)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With these inputs:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Results:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="col-last">Item 3</li>
    <li class="row-last">Item 4</li>
    <li class="row-last">Item 5</li>
    <li class="row-last col-last">Item 6</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="col-last">Item 3</li>
    <li class="row-last">Item 4</li>
    <li class="row-last">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="col-last">Item 3</li>
    <li class="row-last">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** When ouput attributes take notice that last attribute with same name overwrites previous.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer that addresses the stated requirements.

Comment: @Mads Hansen: +1 for "civility"! I hope you'd had your coffee, ja!

Answer (score 1):

You could use another test to see if the `position()` is within 3 of the size of the nodeset using `last()-3`:

This answer does not fully address the stated requirements.  [@Alejandro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288625/xslt-get-last-row-from-a-foreach-loop-split-into-3-columns/3291001#3291001) should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This produce an @class="row-last" (I think you have a type mistake) for every last three. Also, @class="col-last" would overwrite every previous @class.

Comment: @Alejandro - you are right.  I obviously didn't test my solution (and hadn't had my coffee).

Comment: I cannot delete my answer, since it has been accepted. @Marko Ivanovski, would you de-select my answer?

Comment: Thanks to both of you - @Mads - you led me to fix my issue by slightly modifying what you provided, but Alejandro had posted the correct one in the meanwhile. Cheers!